# bash: brew command is not showing any output

Tags: shell, terminal, homebrew, macos-sierra

I accidentally placed the `>` character before the brew command (Homebrew), after that, I'm not sure if the brew commands are being executed because they don't output anything.

I've restarted terminal and computer but it continues the same.

Mac OS X Sierra

Comment: `> brew` truncates a file called `brew`. If the directory you were in is in your path, you're now running that empty file (which explains why they do nothing). If you did it in the dir where `brew` was installed, you essentially deleted it

Comment: That was it, i had to reinstall the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer:

Run the following command to get your `brew` back:

```
$ git -C /usr/local/Homebrew reset --hard origin/master
```

#### Long answer:

As [@that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) pointed out, you created an empty file by using a redirect to `brew`.

```
$ >brew some command
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$ some command > brew
```

Which means you run `some command` and sends its output in a file called `brew`. If that command fails without outputing anything (besides an error), it turns it into an empty file.

One way to avoid this behavior on existing files is to use `set -C`:

```
$ echo foo > myfile
$ echo bar > myfile
$ cat myfile
bar

$ set -C
$ echo foo > myfile
$ echo bar > myfile
bash: myfile: cannot overwrite existing file
$ cat myfile
foo
```

With this set, you have to either delete the target file before redirecting output in it, or use `>|`:

```
$ echo bar > myfile
bas
$ echo bar >| myfile
$ cat myfile
bar
```

However this is only a preventive measure, so once you’ve overwritten your file it’s too late.

To retrieve the original `brew`, reset its git repository (usually `/usr/local/Homebrew`):

```
$ git -C /usr/local/Homebrew reset --hard origin/master
```